# Change url of web application

Tags: solr, web, web.xml

How can I change 'http://localhost:8983/solr/' into 'http://localhost:8983/solr-test/' ?

Reason:
I want to run 2 solr instances (development and test) on one server which have different solr homes.

best regards.

Comment: which application server are you using?

Answer (score 1):

What about using multiple cores?

see: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin

Answer (score 0):

Just change the folder name from solr into solr-test, if u have wamp it's in www directory...

Comment: It really is that simple - rename the directory where the exploded webapp is running OR rename the war file and restart the server.

Comment: Ya already solved the problem. Renaming war file didnt worked - I just thought that..The real problem was the proxy forward. Now all fine!

Comment: this is a brute force way, the multiple cores way is better